# Path with no dependence violations

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I am guessing this will be a duplicate(it seems like a common task), but I obviously can't find the right page. I have a directed graph showing dependencies, and I want to list the vertices  in an order such that for a given vertex, all vertices which leading to it appear prior to it in the list. If a vertex has no verticies leading to it, it is an entry point and has no constraints on where it is placed.

For example with the following graph, I would want an order similar to the one I provide (which I found by hand). I know that many lists satisfy these constraints, but I am just interested in finding a single solution.

[image]

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 3 -> 9, 10 -> 3};
TreePlot[edges, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]

result={1, 2, 10, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8};
```

Comment: Cycles will get you into trouble ...

Comment: I think the nature of the graphs I'm working with will not allow cycles

Comment: You can verify that with `AcyclicGraphQ`.  For plotting, just use `Graph[edges]`, for this simple case, or `Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]` to force the right embedding for directed acyclic graphs. This is not a tree. The old `LayeredGraphPlot` would also do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wanted to have the vertexes labeled and arrows shown and I found this command did that: `Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeShapeFunction -> "Arrow"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 4, 4 -> 8,  3 -> 9, 10 -> 3};
TopologicalSort@Graph@edges

(* {10, 1, 2, 3, 9, 6, 7, 4, 8} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was bound to be a simple solution